# Storing an array of arrays in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, arrays, set

I am making a table of a products like different types of vehicles: cars, trucks etc. They are made by an array of countries and each country has an array of makers, like Japan has Toyota, Honda, etc and US has Ford, GM etc. Once the database is built, I need to do operations like "select all vehicles made by Toyota".

What is the best way to store that?

Comment: You should learn basic database techniques, particularly [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and then you'll be able to answer this yourself.

Comment: Best way is to not use arrays.  Arrays are horrible within databases, if all you are doing is storing arrays, you might as well be referring to a text file somewhere instead.  Do some research on data normalization and how you'd want to store data without using arrays. (MarcB beat me to the comment ;))

Comment: No, I don't have to have arrays. I was thinking about serialize into JSON but suspected this to be a standard database problem. Looks like it is indeed, judging from the swarm of high school genius that down voted every question they know the answer of.

Answer (score 1):

The data structure is not necessarily the same as your array structure. The key word is "normalisation": design your tables in a way that avoids redundancies and make sure that each record in a table contains exactly the information that is relevant to describe the subject of that particular table.

A possible structure could be:

```
create table vehicles(
vid int auto_increment primary key,
void int,
vname nvarchar(32),
vtype int,
vmotor varchar(32), ...)

create table oem (
oid int auto_increment primary key,
oname nvarchar(32),
countryid int, ... )
```

The column `void` of table `vehicles` references the primary key `oid` of the `oem` (original equipment manufacturers) table.

A typical query can be the following:

```
select * from vehicles where 
exists (select 1 from oem where oid=void and countryid=7)
```

`countryid` is just an integer key referencing yet another table (not listed here) containing country names etc.. Assuming that record 7 of the country table contains 'Japan' then the above query will list all vehicles made in Japan.

Or - coming back to your original example -

```
select * from vehicles where 
exists (select 1 from oem where oid=void and oname='Toyota')
```

would list all vehicles of that particular manufacturer.

This little example is just the starting point for you to understand `normalisation'. Like Marc B already said: Study the concept for yourself and you will be able to answer your question yourself. Here is another example based link that might be helpful: http://db.grussell.org/section008.html .

Comment: Good place for me to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a table called Automobiles,
and then rows like Car, Model, Company,Country

and then you can just

```
SELECT * FROM Automobiles WHERE Company = 'Toyota' AND Country = 'Japan'
```

Comment: Thanks Theodore. That would work. This would also mean that each data object expands into a potentially very long table, right? I am OK with that, but want to know if this is the standard way.

Comment: I don't know if it's correct to do, but I have in the past had a column like Settings that basically contians a json array. But there's probably some better ways of using sql, I just don't know them.